# What color options exist for ack(-grep) for colorization of output, logs, etc?

Tags: bash, shell, logging, ack

Where can one find a listing of all color combinations or such available to use with `ack(-grep)`?  I find that passing logs through `ack-grep` can be quite helpful at detecting errors, warnings or various other conditions especially with colorization, however I haven't found an authoritative list of what combos may be used, etc.

```
tail -f development.log \
| ack-grep --flush --passthru --color --color-match=yellow "^.*warning.*"
```

I've seen options such as the standard colors: `red`, `blue`, `yellow`, `green`, etc.

And I've seen that you can use `"white on_green"`

But what else?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

ack uses Perl's `Term::ANSIColor` module, so you can check what is available to you with:

```
perldoc Term::ANSIColor
```

Here's the relevant excerpt.

```
   The recognized normal foreground color attributes (colors 0 to 7) are:

     black  red  green  yellow  blue  magenta  cyan  white

   The corresponding bright foreground color attributes (colors 8 to 15)
   are:

     bright_black  bright_red      bright_green  bright_yellow
     bright_blue   bright_magenta  bright_cyan   bright_white

   The recognized normal background color attributes (colors 0 to 7) are:

     on_black  on_red      on_green  on_yellow
     on_blue   on_magenta  on_cyan   on_white

   The recognized bright background color attributes (colors 8 to 15) are:

     on_bright_black  on_bright_red      on_bright_green  on_bright_yellow
     on_bright_blue   on_bright_magenta  on_bright_cyan   on_bright_white

   For any of the above listed attributes, case is not significant.
```

I'm glad to see you using `--passthru`, too.

We'd welcome you on the [ack-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ack-users)

Comment: I added a ticket for ack 2.0 to explain it: https://github.com/petdance/ack2/issues/26

Comment: On a linux (Ubuntu 11.10) server I'm seeing that the `bright_` are evoking an error: `Invalid attribute name bright_black at /usr/share/perl5/App/Ack.pm line 1155` - Should this be brought over to the mailing list at this point?

Comment: It's really a Term::ANSIColor issue, but sure, bring it to ack-users.

Answer (score 10):

Another interesting thing to do is to create a ~/.ackrc with default configuration like:

```
--color
--color-match=on_white
--color-filename=red
--color-lineno=magenta
```

To get readable results on white console background for instance. (Actually the reason why I started to search and found this question and the helpful reply from @andy-lester).

Comment: I had the same problem. Thanks!|
What if  when using ag?? is there a solution for that